# Algorithm to estimate total active time from timestamps

Tags: algorithm, datetime, timestamp

Say I have a a series of timestamps (from visitor impressions), and it looks like (omitting dates):

```
01:02:13
01:03:29
01:04:34
02:19:29
09:45:10
09:46:20
.....
```

In the above case, I'd want to sum up the time passed from the first 4 timestamps (1 to 2AM), and separate them from the 9AM events.

Is there a clever way to estimate combined active time, other than utilizing a timeout (say a 300+ seconds timeout indicates a new session). If not, what's a standard / good timeout to use?

Comment: A series of timestamps does not contain sufficient information to estimate active time. Your example demonstrates this fairly clearly. Although the 1AM events are likely the same session, the data is insufficient to determine whether the 2AM event was a) the continuation of the 1AM session, b) the beginning of the 9AM session, or c) a separate aborted session.

Comment: Yea I was wondering if there was a well known good estimation approach. I mean Google Analytics estimates average time spent on the website etc, they had to use some kind of approximation, right?

Comment: I suspect that there's more to it than just a series of timestamps. *"How does Google Analytics estimate session times?"* is a whole different question than the one you asked.